# How to call child component(view <child-app>) and router-outlet in parent component

Tags: javascript, angular, routes, angular2-routing

I need both router-outlet and child component to be in the section.
is there any way we can do it using routing

parent component(HTML)-app.component.html

```
<ul *ngFor="let report of repcategory.Reports">
    <li>
      <a href="" class="nav-link py-1"                      
       (click)="viz(report.Link,report.Name,report.helpfile,report.helpvideo)">                        
       {{report.Name}}
      </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div>
     <section>
      <app-viz [showreportEvent]="showreportEvent.asObservable()"></app-viz> //child component          
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
     </section>
</div>
```

parent component(ts)-app.component.ts

```
viz(x,y,z,z2) {
    this.showreportEvent.next({repurl: x, repname: y}); 
}
```

Comment: So do you want a single route to show two different components?

Comment: Hey @DaneBrouwer ,kind of, I need the child to be in router-outlet and if I write any other routings those should be also in the place of <app-viz>

Comment: Do you want it to show for every route? or just for specific ones?

Comment: How you currently have it should work, whats the issue?

Comment: in the <section>  I need to show the <app-viz> whenever I click on any <li> item, and when any router links occur in the application those should be routed to router-outlet in the same section, hiding <app-viz>

Answer (score 0):

#### This can be done by listening to router change events:

```js
constructor(router: Router) {
  // all router events
  router.events
    // filter events other than navigationStart out
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
    // subscribe to the result
    .subscribe(event => {
      // set showreportEvent to null
      this.showreportEvent.next(null);
    });
}
```

Then all you need to do in `<app-viz>` is to check if the observable is `null`. If it is null, then hide the content.

Otherwise, you could always just use an `ngIf` on `<app-viz>`.